# Scrapy: How to stop CrawlSpider after 100 requests

Tags: scrapy

I would like to limit the amount of pages CrawlSpider is visiting on website.

How can I stop the Scrapy CrawlSpider after 100 requests?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use closespider extension for that with the `CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT` setting. According to the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#std-setting-CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT):

> ... specifies the maximum number of responses to crawl. If the spider
> crawls more than that, the spider will be closed with the reason
> `closespider_pagecount`

All you would need to do is set in your settings.py:

```
CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 100
```

If this doesn't suit your need, another approach could be writing your own extension using Scrapy's [stats](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html#topics-stats) module to keep track of number of requests.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Unfortunately this is not working for me. Do I have to load the extension somehow before? I Added CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 2 to my settings but the crawler does not stop.

Comment: Hi @PhilippS. It's a default extension, so threre should be no need to explicitly load it. What is your scrapy version? Please try to run your spider overriding the settings, like this: `scrapy crawl your_spider_name -s CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT=2`. Keep in mind that that extension counts responses, not requests, they should add up but sometimes they don't.